# Is it possible to change a column name in Spark SQL in Hive?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, hive

I'm trying to rename a column (date type), but wasn't sure if the syntax was wrong or if this just isn't possible in Spark SQL:

```
ALTER TABLE user.temp_medicalclaims 
CHANGE vendor_test_id date_service DATE
```

brings up this error:

> org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: ALTER TABLE CHANGE COLUMN is
>   not supported for changing column 'vendor_test_id' with type
>   'DateType' to 'date_service' with type 'DateType';

Answer (score 4):

I don't think its still possible with Spark and there is an open [SPARK-21823](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-21823) jira addressing same issue.

- We still need to use **`Hive/Beeline`** to change column names in the table.

**(or)**

- Dropping the table and recreating the table with new column names using Spark.